# How to use GAP to cumpute $S=\{s|s=h^2, h\in H\}$ for every subgroup $H$ of $G$?

Tags: gap, computer-algebra-systems

Let $G$ be a finite group, then how to use GAP to cumpute $S=\{s|s=h^2, h\in H\}$ for every subgroup $H$ of $G$?

Comment: Do you want the set of all squares? Or do you assume that the squares form/generate a subgroup?

Comment: @ahulpke, uh, I want the set of all squares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every element lies in a subgroup, this is just the set $\{h^2| h\in G\}$. So calculate the conjugacy classes, check which classes are squares (the classes of elements of odd order and those of even order into which other classes square) and take the elements of these classes.

Comment: Thank you very much! uh, let G be a finite group, do you know how to use GAP to get $SG=\{g^2|g\in G\}$.

Comment: @YiWang I told you that already in the answer. Read from "So calculate the conjugacy classes ..."

Comment: @ahupke, Ok! Thank you very much!